# ZF2 service locator & dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, phpunit, zend-framework2, service-locator

The good people at Zend, and a number of bloggers, are recommending the new service locator/manager for ZF2, rather than its inbuilt Dependency Injection system.

My question is, is it possible/convenient to inject mock objects into a service?  I have seen some slightly clumsy attempts to do this in the PHPUnit bootstrap of a module; but is there a way of using this service system that is as clean and convenient as, say, ZF1 + Yadif?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can inject mock objects into a service. For an unit test, the service locator does not even come into play:

```
$service = new MyService($mockDependency);
```

If you are writing complex integration tests where you need to use the Service Locator to be configured with a graph of dependencies and mocks, you can setup something like what I am doing with my modules:

```
$serviceLocator   = ServiceManagerFactory::getServiceManager(); // see comment below
$dbConnectionMock = $this->getMock('My\Db\Connection');

$serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(true);
// replacing connection service with our fake one
$serviceLocator->setService('connection_service_name', $dbConnectionMock);

$service = $serviceLocator->get('service_that_uses_a_connection');
```

You can find an example of `ServiceManagerFactory` in `DoctrineORMModule` at https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/0.7.0/tests/DoctrineORMModuleTest/Util/ServiceManagerFactory.php

This works assuming that `service_that_uses_a_connection` is instantiated by a factory that injects `connection_service_name` into it.

You can still use also `Zend\Di` if you prefer to, but it's not really needed in such cases.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Hopefully one day the Zend documentation will be this clear!

Comment: @AgileTillIDie please DO contribute yourself! https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation - if you got no GIT-fu, you can still edit it online in the Github UI.